# PIC24F32KA302 Sleep mode

Tags: sleep, microcontroller, pic24

I want to configure PIC24F32KA302 to go to Sleep mode and wake up by RTC interrupt. However, after waking up, my program runs again from the beginning. The datasheet mentions that:
- If the assigned priority for the interrupt is less than or equal to the current CPU priority, the device will wake-up and continue code execution from the instruction following the PWRSAV instruction that initiated Sleep mode.
- If the assigned priority level for the interrupt source is greater than the current CPU priority, the device will wake-up and the CPU exception process will begin. Code execution will continue from the first instruction of the ISR.
I tried both configurations but the results are the same.
My code is below:

```
int main(void) {
SYS_Init();
while(1){
    __delay_ms(400);
    Sleep();
}
return 0;}

void __attribute__ ( (interrupt, no_auto_psv) )  _RTCCInterrupt(void) {
IFS3bits.RTCIF = 0;
//To do:
Total_Pulse += TMR1;
TMR1 = 0;
LED = ~LED;}

void InterruptPriority_Init(void) {
INTCON1bits.NSTDIS = 1;
INTCON2bits.ALTIVT = 0;
SRbits.IPL = 1;
IPC15bits.RTCIP = 6;//6
_U2RXIP = 5;
_T1IP = 4;
_U1RXIP = 2;
_HLVDIP = 3;}
```

The function SYS_Init() initializes interrupt, RTC and other peripheral modules. This function always runs after device wakes up from Sleep mode.
Do you have any idea or advice for me? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It could very well be some sort of errors happening causing your device to reset.

Did you add the trap routines ? If not, add this code and see if you get into one of those trap.

Also make sure you don't have any power drop in your circuit and that your reset pin is not getting some sort of noise, you can add a 100nF capacitor between the reset pin and GND (of course keeping the pullup).

```
/******************************************************************************/
/* Files to Include                                                           */
/******************************************************************************/

/* Device header file */
#if defined(__XC16__)
    #include <xc.h>
#elif defined(__C30__)
    #if defined(__PIC24E__)
        #include <p24Exxxx.h>
    #elif defined (__PIC24F__)||defined (__PIC24FK__)
    #include <p24Fxxxx.h>
    #elif defined(__PIC24H__)
    #include <p24Hxxxx.h>
    #endif
#endif

#include <stdint.h>        /* Includes uint16_t definition */
#include <stdbool.h>       /* Includes true/false definition */

/******************************************************************************/
/* Trap Function Prototypes                                                   */
/******************************************************************************/

/* <Other function prototypes for debugging trap code may be inserted here>   */

/* Use if INTCON2 ALTIVT=1 */
void __attribute__((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _OscillatorFail(void);
void __attribute__((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _AddressError(void);
void __attribute__((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _StackError(void);
void __attribute__((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _MathError(void);

#if defined(__PIC24F__)||defined(__PIC24H__)

/* Use if INTCON2 ALTIVT=0 */
void __attribute__((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _AltOscillatorFail(void);
void __attribute__((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _AltAddressError(void);
void __attribute__((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _AltStackError(void);
void __attribute__((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _AltMathError(void);

#endif

/* Default interrupt handler */
void __attribute__((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _DefaultInterrupt(void);

#if defined(__PIC24E__)

/* These are additional traps in the 24E family.  Refer to the PIC24E
migration guide.  There are no Alternate Vectors in the 24E family. */
void __attribute__((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _HardTrapError(void);
void __attribute__((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _DMACError(void);
void __attribute__((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _SoftTrapError(void);

#endif

/******************************************************************************/
/* Trap Handling                                                              */
/*                                                                            */
/* These trap routines simply ensure that the device continuously loops       */
/* within each routine.  Users who actually experience one of these traps     */
/* can add code to handle the error.  Some basic examples for trap code,      */
/* including assembly routines that process trap sources, are available at    */
/* www.microchip.com/codeexamples                                             */
/******************************************************************************/

/* Primary (non-alternate) address error trap function declarations */
void __attribute__((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _OscillatorFail(void)
{
        INTCON1bits.OSCFAIL = 0;        /* Clear the trap flag */
        while(1);
}

void __attribute__((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _AddressError(void)
{
        INTCON1bits.ADDRERR = 0;        /* Clear the trap flag */
        while (1);
}
void __attribute__((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _StackError(void)
{
        INTCON1bits.STKERR = 0;         /* Clear the trap flag */
        while (1);
}

void __attribute__((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _MathError(void)
{
        INTCON1bits.MATHERR = 0;        /* Clear the trap flag */
        while (1);
}

#if defined(__PIC24F__)||defined(__PIC24H__)

/* Alternate address error trap function declarations */
void __attribute__((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _AltOscillatorFail(void)
{
        INTCON1bits.OSCFAIL = 0;        /* Clear the trap flag */
        while (1);
}

void __attribute__((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _AltAddressError(void)
{
        INTCON1bits.ADDRERR = 0;        /* Clear the trap flag */
        while (1);
}

void __attribute__((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _AltStackError(void)
{
        INTCON1bits.STKERR = 0;         /* Clear the trap flag */
        while (1);
}

void __attribute__((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _AltMathError(void)
{
        INTCON1bits.MATHERR = 0;        /* Clear the trap flag */
        while (1);
}

#endif

/******************************************************************************/
/* Default Interrupt Handler                                                  */
/*                                                                            */
/* This executes when an interrupt occurs for an interrupt source with an     */
/* improperly defined or undefined interrupt handling routine.                */
/******************************************************************************/
void __attribute__((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _DefaultInterrupt(void)
{
        while(1);
}

#if defined(__PIC24E__)

/* These traps are new to the PIC24E family.  Refer to the device Interrupt
chapter of the FRM to understand trap priority. */
void __attribute__((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _HardTrapError(void)
{
    while(1);
}
void __attribute__((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _DMACError(void)
{
    while(1);
}
void __attribute__((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _SoftTrapError(void)
{
    while(1);
}

#endif
```